# Firebase shallow query parameter for android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the following link, there's a shallow option available for Firebase queries:

[Shallow Query in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow)

Is it supported also in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

None of the Firebase SDKs support shallow queries against the database. They all retrieve entire nodes.

The only Firebase Database API that supports shallow queries is the REST API.

See:

- [Firebase (2016) Shallow Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365866/firebase-2016-shallow-query)
- [How do I retrieve arbitrary Firebase children from shallow level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732495/how-do-i-retrieve-arbitrary-firebase-children-from-shallow-level)
- [firebase getting only keys then getting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637951/firebase-getting-only-keys-then-getting-data/31638051#31638051)