# How to fetch item1 : item2 : item3 itself not there values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase database structure :

-Main

---item1: "Structure"

---item2: "good"

---item3: "something"

+users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mainRef = rootRef.child("Main");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String item = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
mainRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And your output will be:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

Comment: While this will only **print** the keys, it will still **fetch** the values too. There is no way in the Firebase SDKs to fetch just the keys. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41590730/firebase-shallow-query-parameter-for-android

Comment: How can I print these outputs in a list view

Comment: I recomand you using [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).